# Grails simple registration/login form

Tags: grails, authentication, registration

I've created completely new Grails project and then used **grails s2-quickstart** command to obtain LoginController and User/UserRole classes. Everything works fine, I have a login page. Then, I created User Controller in GTS by choosing "generate controller and views". The generated UserController looks as follows:

```
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class UserController {

static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    respond User.list(params), model:[userInstanceCount: User.count()]
}

def show(User userInstance) {
    respond userInstance
}

def create() {
    respond new User(params)
}

@Transactional
def save(User userInstance) {
    if (userInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (userInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond userInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    userInstance.save flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), userInstance.id])
            redirect userInstance
        }
        '*' { respond userInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}

def edit(User userInstance) {
    respond userInstance
}

@Transactional
def update(User userInstance) {
    if (userInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (userInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond userInstance.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }

    userInstance.save flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'User.label', default: 'User'), userInstance.id])
            redirect userInstance
        }
        '*'{ respond userInstance, [status: OK] }
    }
}

@Transactional
def delete(User userInstance) {

    if (userInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    userInstance.delete flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'User.label', default: 'User'), userInstance.id])
            redirect action:"index", method:"GET"
        }
        '*'{ render status: NO_CONTENT }
    }
}

protected void notFound() {
    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), params.id])
            redirect action: "index", method: "GET"
        }
        '*'{ render status: NOT_FOUND }
    }
}
```

}

Now, when I want to go to /user/index page it forwards me to login page... 
How to change that? I'm completely new to Grails so sorry if this question is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide access to user/index to a specific Role by either specifying spring security controller annotation static rules in your config file or using Secured annotation on controllers.

Reference : http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#secured-annotation

http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#pessimistic-lockdown

Comment: Ok, but I want this UserController to be accessed by anyone, not logged user which doesn't have a role. Should I add ROLE_ANONYMOUS.?

Comment: Add it to your static rules and follow existing rules permitAll @user2455862 in your application.groovy